# how do I display different data by clicking two buttons in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a layout with two buttons. I want to be able to click on each button to display its content. Also each button should be a toggle to either display the contents or not.

```
function Update() {
  
  const [showFirst, setShowFirst] = useState(false);
  const [showSecond, setShowSecond] = useState(false);
  
 
  return (
    <Wrapper>
          <main
          <h3>CHANGE FACILITY</h3>
         
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
            <Link
              onClick={() => setShowFirst(!showFirst)}
            >
              First content
            </Link>
            
            <Button
              onClick={() => setShowSecond(!showSecond)}
            >
             Second content
            </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <main>
      
      
      
       <div style={showSecond? {display:"none"} : {display:"block"}}>
       {showFirst && (<h3>Ist facility</h3>)}
       </div>
       

       <div style={showFirst? {display:"none"} : {display:"block"}}>
       {showSecond && (<h3>2nd facility</h3>)}
       </div>
       
    
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

When I click on the ShowFirst button it renders both content and the ShowSecond button does not toggle. Please I need a guide to make each button display its content when its button is clicked and also toggle action on each button click.

Comment: Plz describe the expected behaviour in detail.

Comment: First, you click ShowFirst Button, then "Ist facility" should be shown, and then you click ShowSecond Button, then "1st facility" disappears and f2nd facility should be shown. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. You are already pretty close.

```js
function Update() {

    // Set tabIndex to 1 by default to show the first tab on load
    const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(1);
    
   
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <main>
                <h3>CHANGE FACILITY</h3>
           
                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
                    <button onClick={() => setTabIndex(1)}>
                        First content
                    </button>
                    
                    <button onClick={() => setTabIndex(2)}>
                        Second content
                    </button>
                </div>
            </main>
        
        {
            tabIndex === 1 && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Ist facility</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }
        {
            tabIndex === 2 && (
                <div>
                    <h3>2nd facility</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but both contents still display.

Comment: Ah sorry i have misread your question.
The code above has been updated to make sure only 1 tab is visible at all times.
@First Arachne his solution also works but becomes hard to maintain quickly once more facilities get added.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to trying the following.

```
function Update() {
  
    const [showFirst, setShowFirst] = useState(false);
    const [showSecond, setShowSecond] = useState(false);
    
   
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <main>
                <h3>CHANGE FACILITY</h3>
           
                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                      setShowFirst(!showFirst);
                      setShowSecond(false);
                    }}>
                        First content
                    </button>
                    
                    <button onClick={() => {
                      setShowSecond(!showSecond);
                      setShowFirst(false);
                    }}>
                        Second content
                    </button>
                </div>
            </main>
        
        {
            showFirst && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Ist facility</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }
        {
            showSecond && (
                <div>
                    <h3>2nd facility</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```